# Capital gains while living abroad?

Tags: united-states, capital-gains-tax, foreign-income, working-abroad

Let's say I'm a U.S citizen and have money in a brokerage account at a U.S institution, but I have moved to Germany. Let's imagine that this money generates capital gains. Assuming that I have to pay taxes on these gains in Germany, how are those gains treated by the U.S tax code?

What if the gains are generated at an institution in Germany? How does the U.S tax code treat the gains then?

Comment: What country are you living in, and what is the country of your citizenship? If you are a US citizen or permanent immigrant to the US, then you have to file a US income tax return and pay incline tax to the US on your world-wide income regardless if where you actually live.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I'm a U.S citizen soon to move to Germany. I edited the question to reflect that. I'm aware that the U.S is one of only two countries in the world that taxes their citizens who live abroad. Thankfully, though not ideally, you get to apply your foreign taxes as a tax credit against your U.S taxes and you get to exempt around $100,000 from your income. However, this only applies to earned income, I haven't been able to find what happens to unearned income, like capital gains, thus my question.

Comment: You've answered yourself. Only earned income can be _excluded_, so you must report these items on your US return and include them in your tax calculation, but you get a credit for foreign tax(es) paid _up to but not exceeding the US tax_ (pro rata by category, see form 1116 and instructions), so you actually _pay_ US tax only if and to the extent it exceeds the foreign tax(es). PS @Dilip: income not incline :-)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Dang auto-complete!

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 So in a nutshell, it's treated the same as earned income but without the "exclusion" benefit, only the "foreign tax credit" benefit. Right?

Comment: Not _just_ the same; US Federal tax applies lower rates, and similar but not same brackets/progressivity, to _long term_ capital gains, defined normally as those on an asset held more than one year. (There are, as always in US taxes, exceptions or variations for some special cases. If you are concerned with a special case, ask a specific question.) But you don't get the exclusion and do get the credit, that's right.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Yeah, yeah, I'm aware of the different rates for long and short term capital gains. My only concern was double taxation, which the foreign tax credit addresses. Of course, ideally the U.S would behave like any other country and would stop taxing their expats altogether, but that's wishful thinking.

Comment: So are we saying you can choose where to pay capital gains tax from US bank accounts (Germany or US), as long as you pay them _somewhere_? And if I pay them in Germany, then I can get it at least credited in the US so I don't pay twice?

Comment: @Matthias You don't get to choose. You first pay taxes to whatever country you reside in, and then to the U.S whatever is left after applying the credits.